# javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction (JPA without Spring)

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Developing a client-server application for a database. There were problems with addNewRestTrip, although I made it as similar as possible to addNewCargoTrip. But I still get a RollbackException.
By the way, I use java without Spring framework, but I use JPA
stack trace

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:81)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
at repository.RepositoryPostgres.addNewRestTrip(RepositoryPostgres.java:141)
at service.Service.addNewRestTrip(Service.java:61)
at api.Controller.addNewRestTrip(Controller.java:55)
at infrastructure.ui.tourist.PlanRestTrip.lambda$new$1(PlanRestTrip.java:90)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:65)
... 40 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:109)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3235)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3760)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1352)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:443)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3202)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2370)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
... 39 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "excursion_pk"
Подробности: Ключ "(id)=(1)" уже существует.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2510)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2245)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:311)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:447)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:368)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:159)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
... 58 more
```

addNewRestTrip (not worked)

```
public void addNewRestTrip(Long id, String country, Timestamp dateIn, Timestamp dateOut, List<Excursion> joinedExcursions) {
    EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        Tourist tourist = entityManager.find(Tourist.class, id);
        Trip trip = new Trip();
        trip.setCountry(country);
        trip.setDate_in(dateIn);
        trip.setDate_out(dateOut);
        trip.setTourist(tourist);
        trip.setRoom(null);
        trip.setExcursions(new ArrayList<>());
        trip.getExcursions().addAll(joinedExcursions);
        entityManager.persist(trip);
        joinedExcursions.forEach(c -> c.getParticipatingTourists().add(trip));
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
     entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

addNewCargoTrip (the same, but worked)

```
public void addNewCargoTrip(Long id, String statement, String country, Timestamp dateIn, Timestamp dateOut) {
    EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
    List<Cargo> cargo = entityManager
            .createQuery("select c from Cargo c where c.statement.id = :statement", Cargo.class)
            .setParameter("statement", Integer.parseInt(statement))
            .getResultList();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    Tourist tourist = entityManager.find(Tourist.class, id);
    Trip trip = new Trip();
    trip.setCountry(country);
    trip.setDate_in(dateIn);
    trip.setDate_out(dateOut);
    trip.setTourist(tourist);
    trip.setRoom(null);
    trip.setCargos(new ArrayList<>());
    trip.getCargos().addAll(cargo);
    entityManager.persist(trip);
    cargo.forEach(c -> c.setOwnerTrip(trip));
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
}
```

project you can see on [github](https://github.com/sweetlover47/DB) (it's scary)

Comment: did you see that `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: повторяющееся значение ключа нарушает ограничение уникальности "excursion_pk"
Подробности: Ключ "(id)=(1)" уже существует.` ? you should translate for us ;-)

Comment: Well i used google translate on this comment and i got a very clear error why this happened: ERROR: duplicate key value violates uniqueness constraint "excursion_pk" Details: Key "(id) = (1)" already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are manually giving your Excursions an id. And when that id already exists in the database you cannot insert it.

There are 2 ways you can go about that:

- The first way is to check which is the latest id in the `excursions` table and give your entities incrementally higher ids.
- The second way (my prefered way) is to let the database handle the ids. Chances are you already have a sequence for every numeric table id. If you don't you should change their types to an autoincrementing type (e.g. SERIAL/BIGSERIAL for Postgresql). After that just simply add `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` after the `@Id` annotation on your entities and **don't** give your entities an id when inserting them (it'll be automatically generated).

*Important note*: since you already have inserted entries to the database you may need to set the starting value of the id sequence to be equal to the last row's id + 1.

Answer (score 0):

in my issue i was created data manually and don't remember to set value for version column.so when i try to update row of database i see this error because this column cannot update from null value to int value